# Side effects in Fluxible?

Tags: side-effects, fluxible

Here's what I'm trying to do---add a listener to a fluxible event to do an ajax call. In Redux, this is called a *side effect* and there are several ways of doing this (ex: create "side effects" using `redux-saga`, which are just listeners that do stuff). In Flux, one approach is to do side effects in the Store.

What about fluxible?

From what I can tell, the way to do this is in the Store. But I don't see a way to get the context. So perhaps there's another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do ajax call in action. Action receives context, where you could provide plugin to do http call. Stores should contain only application state and have only synchronous code.